# Can't set canvas's background in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I got a little problem with my Unity's canvas. I can't set the background image.I've added the Image component to the canvas and I've tried drag the image from the assets to Source Image, but it doesn't allowed that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the image to a Sprite (2D and UI) in order to use it in the canvas. This is done by selecting the image in the Project window and making the change in the Inspector window, from the Texture Type dropdown. Make sure you hit apply once you have completed the changes.